# How to pipe a user input after a command

Tags: command-line, bash, input

I'm trying to automatize the call of the library ADB to connect to android.

The command pair ask to user for a code, so I was thinking if there is a way to do all in the same call.

```
C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb pair localhost:12333
Enter pairing code:
```

I want to know if there is something like:

```
adb pair localhost:12333 | echo 44335
```

to avoid the user the need to enter the code after launching the command.

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Try `echo 44335|adb pair localhost:12333`

Comment: seems that it's not doing it so well. Thank you

Comment: You tagged [tag:bash] but the prompt looks like from `cmd.exe`. Is the tag right?

Comment: No is a simulation, i'm talking about a shell of bash in android